# Execute multiple functions at same time in Jython 2.5

Tags: java, python, concurrency, parallel-processing, jython

I'm trying to run multiple Jython files at the same time so that I can use my PC multiprocessor (specifically doing this in FDM in Hyperion's Workspace)

Is there any way I could do this?

I've tried to do it through Java, but it doesn't recognize the thread function, also tried through Python, and this version of Jython doesn't have the concurrency library, and not able to import it.

```
import os
import sys
from java.io import *
from java.util import *
from java import *
from java.lang import *
from threading import *
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;


new Thread() { 
    public void run() {
        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test1.py")
    }
}.start()
new Thread() { 
    public void run() {
        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test2.py")
    }
}.start()
new Thread() { 
    public void run() {
        java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test3.py")
    }
}.start()
```

Errors:

```
File "E:\Oracle\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1\products\FinancialDataQuality\Applications\FDMEE/data/scripts/custom/test.py", line 15
    new Thread() {
       ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input 'Thread' expecting NEWLINE
```

Comment: What could be wrong?

Comment: For once you're using Java syntax in Python file, but also it is incorrect java syntax. There is no class, no `main` method.

Comment: That's how jython Work's, isn't it?

Comment: No, this is not how Jython works. Jython is a Python interpreter written in Java. It interprets *python* programs. You can use Java library from python, but that's all. You cannot write in Java syntax.

Comment: oh, I understand, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Java syntax in python code. Even if you're running it with Jython.

You can use the fact that Jython will convert python functions to Java functional interface.

```
from java.lang import Thread, Runtime


Thread(lambda: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test1.py")).start()
Thread(lambda: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test2.py")).start()
Thread(lambda: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test3.py")).start()
```

Pythonic way to do the same would be

```
import subprocess, threading

threading.Thread(target=lambda: subprocess.call(["python","test1.py"])).start()
threading.Thread(target=lambda: subprocess.call(["python","test2.py"])).start()
```

To be honest I would use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`, but I am not sure if Jython supports it.

Comment: Im not sure, but I'm getting this error with your code:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 528, in executeJythonScript
  File "E:\Oracle\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1\products\FinancialDataQuality\Applications\FDMEE/data/scripts/custom/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    Thread(lambda: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test1.py")).start()
TypeError: java.lang.Thread(): 1st arg can't be coerced to java.lang.Runnable, String

Comment: It works for me with Java 8 and Jython 2.7. What versions are you using?

Comment: I just checked, automatic conversion of python functions to Java single method interfaces was added to Jython 2.5.2

Comment: Hy, im using Jython2.5 and Java 6

Comment: @CamiloD'Achiardi I've edited my answer to show how to do what you're trying to do in pure Python. That should work with Jython 2.5 (I tested on Jython 2.5.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answered my question! :D